# Error trying to get a value from Azure table storage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, azure, azure-table-storage

I have so far been unable to query my Azure table from JavaScript. I followed the steps at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx, describing how to authenticate the request, but so far I only get an Ajax error callback. Does anyone know what is going wrong here? Below is the code that I used:

CORS code (C# Console Application):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {

    private const String ACCOUNT_NAME = "<ACCOUNT_NAME>";
    private const String ACCOUNT_KEY = "<ACCOUNT_KEY>";

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private CloudTableClient makeTableClient() {
        String connectionString = "AccountName=" + ACCOUNT_NAME + ";AccountKey=" + ACCOUNT_KEY + ";DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        return tableClient;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        addRule(makeTableClient());
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        removeRule(makeTableClient());
    }

    public void addRule(CloudTableClient tableClient) {
        try {
            CorsRule corsRule = new CorsRule() {
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string> { "*" },
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Connect | CorsHttpMethods.Delete | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Merge
                  | CorsHttpMethods.Options | CorsHttpMethods.Post | CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Trace,
                //Since we'll only be calling Query Tables, let's just allow GET verb
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string> { "*" }, //This is the URL of our application.
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string> { "*" },
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 1 * 60 * 60, //Let the browser cache it for an hour
            };
            ServiceProperties serviceProperties = tableClient.GetServiceProperties();
            CorsProperties corsSettings = serviceProperties.Cors;
            corsSettings.CorsRules.Add(corsRule);
            tableClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            txtOutput.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void removeRule(CloudTableClient tableClient) {
        try {
            ServiceProperties serviceProperties = tableClient.GetServiceProperties();
            CorsProperties corsSettings = serviceProperties.Cors;
            corsSettings.CorsRules.RemoveAt(0);
            tableClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            txtOutput.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

HTML/JavaScript code:

```
    function CallTableStorage() {
        var accountName = "<ACCOUNT_NAME>";
        var tableName = "<TABLE_NAME>";
        var userId = "<PARTITION_AND_ROW_KEY>";
        var secretKey = "<ACCOUNT_KEY>";

        var partitionKey = userId;
        var rowKey = userId;
        var queryString = encodeURIComponent(tableName + "(PartitionKey='" + partitionKey + "',RowKey='" + rowKey + "')");
        var urlPath = "https://" + accountName + ".table.core.windows.net/" + queryString + "?$select=adid";

        var VERB = "GET";
        var contentMD5 = "";
        var contentType = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
        var date = (new Date()).toUTCString();
        var canonicalizedResource = "/" + accountName + "/" + queryString;

        stringToSign = VERB + "\n" + 
               contentMD5 + "\n" + 
               contentType + "\n" +
               date + "\n" +
               canonicalizedResource;

        var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(stringToSign), CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(secretKey)));

        $.ajax({
            url: urlPath,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success:', data);
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version', '2014-02-14');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-date', date);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "SharedKey " + accountName + ":" + signature);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=nometadata');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('DataServiceVersion', '3.0;NetFx');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('MaxDataServiceVersion', '3.0;NetFx');
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = CallTableStorage;
```

Comment: So what does the error say?

Comment: Whoops! Left that out. I edited the code a little to output the success and error callback functions to the console to see the details. I also added a missing line xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); that apparently was needed (based on an error I was seeing). Currently, the error I see is: This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.

Comment: I also see this from the debugger: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. This likely is the real reason - I'll keep digging.

Comment: Could you post the value of a sample stringToSign? At a glance, it looks like the contentType you are using in stringToSign is never set in the Content-Type header of the request.

Comment: A sample stringToSign looks like:
---
GET

text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Mon, 22 Jun 2015 12:37:57 GMT
/rbatest/Ads(PartitionKey%3D'johndoe%40microsoft.com'%2CRowKey%3D'johndoe%40microsoft.com')
---
I tried removing content-type from stringToSign (as suggested below) and adding xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'); but got the same results. I would have expected that not to work, given that the documentation says that StringToSign should look like:
StringToSign = VERB + "\n" + Content-MD5 + "\n" + Content-Type + "\n" + Date + "\n" + CanonicalizedResource;

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing content-type from your stringToSign and see if that works? Or, as Michael Roberson suggested, add a setRequestHeader for Content-Type and see if that works.

Also, if this javascript/html is for a client side app you should be cautious as your account key will be sent in plain text.